# Is there any 3rd party service to give me the required fields that I need to make a international bank transfer by country code?

Tags: web-services, banking

Is there any way to get the required fields/data for the user to provide to allow me to do a bank transfer to the user based on the country code?

For users from the USA, I would ask them to give me

country
city
address
company
identification
state
postcode

Is there any 3rd party service to give me the required fields that I need to make a international bank transfer by country code?